# Simba SRL6 - minE function

Tags: simba

I have seen this code for the SRL6 Simba scripting language based on Delphi

```
    dist:= hypot(xs - xe, ys - ye);
    wind:= minE(wind, dist);
    if (dist < 1) then
      dist := 1;
    PDist := (dist/TDist);
```

And

```
    if (getSystemTime() > t) then
      break;

    dist:= hypot(xs - xe, ys - ye);
    wind:= minE(wind, dist);
```

Really, we are focusing on the bottom line of the last snippet - **minE(..)**. What could this function mean? I know it's mathematical, and yes I've Googled for an hour with no avail! Thanks for the help

Comment: There is a possible inverse function, called MaxE() also. Neither of these availed good search results, due to Google finding them too similar to common words.

Comment: this is nothign about Delphi, that is only about Simba language ans SRL library. There seems to be no MINE function at http://docs.villavu.com/simba/referencescript.html so i think you should trace into MINE functions in Simba IDE or find the function in https://github.com/SRL/SRL-6  Anyway, to find people knowing Simba you better go Simba forum http://villavu.com/forum/ and ask there. This has no relation to Delphi so asking it here is just to hope for sheer luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinE is only a wrapper for extended values. As seen in this example:

```
function ps_MinE(a, b : extended) : extended; extdecl;
begin
  result := min(a,b);
end;
```